# rename all files sequentially with same extension using batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I wanna rename this files like that:

```
File 1.pdf  > 1.pdf
File 2.pdf  > 2.pdf
..
File 10.pdf >10.pdf
File 11.pdf >11.pdf
File1 1.pdf >12.pdf      
File1 2.pdf >13.pdf
..
```

This code it's working but not Sorting Them:

```
    @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
  ren "%%i" "!a!.pdf" 
  set /a a+=1
)
```

The result is :

```
File 1.pdf  > 1.pdf
File 10.pdf > 2.pdf
File 11.pdf > 3.pdf
```

Comment: They're sorted correctly now. The digits are being displayed in their ASCII order, which means that `1`, `10`, '11` is correct. If you want them sorted differently, adjust the filename to left-pad them with zeros to the same number of digits (`01`, `02`, etc.). This will sort them more numerically correctly.

Comment: Yes, I know Thank you, but i'm searching to do it by modifying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1" == "stage1" goto :stage1
if "%~1" == "stage2" goto :stage2
if not "%~1" == "" exit /b 1

cmd /c "%~f0" stage1 | sort | cmd /c "%~f0" stage2
exit /b 0

:stage1
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        set "token1=%%~B                             "
        set "token2=                             %%~C"
        echo "!token1:~0,20!"^|"!token2:~-20!"^|"%%~A"
    )
)
exit /b 0

:stage2
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('more') do (
    set /a "i+=1"
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=|" %%B in ("%%~A") do (
        echo ren "%%~B" "!i!.pdf"
    )
)
exit /b 0
```

Label `stage1` pads the 2 tokens of the filename with spaces and then trims each to 20 characters in length. Each line is echoed with `"token1 padded"|"token2 padded"|"full filename"`, which is piped to `sort`, and then piped to label `stage2` for indexing and renaming.

Remove the echo in front of the `ren` command if test is good.

Output:

> ```
> ren "File 1.pdf" "1.pdf"
> ren "File 2.pdf" "2.pdf"
> ren "File 10.pdf" "3.pdf"
> ren "File 11.pdf" "4.pdf"
> ren "File1 1.pdf" "5.pdf"
> ren "File1 2.pdf" "6.pdf"
> ```

Comment: Thanks So much !  it works for me you are brilliant .

Answer (score 0):

You can test `a` to see if it is less than 10 and add a zero to the filename like this:

```
if !a! LSS 10 ren "%%i" "0!a!.pdf" else ren "%%i" "!a!.pdf"
```

If you have more than 100 file to rename, you can make it like this:

```
if !a! LSS 10 set newfile="00!a!" else if !a! LSS 100 set newfile="0!a!"

ren "%%i" "!newfile!.pdf"
```

Putting it all together, this worked for me:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
  set newfile="!a!"
  if !a! LSS 1000 set newfile="0!a!"
  if !a! LSS 100 set newfile="00!a!"
  if !a! LSS 10 set newfile="000!a!"

  ren "%%i" "!newfile!.pdf"
  set /a a+=1
)
```

Comment: thank you ! I Have tried but it doesn't work i have 1000 files named like that( File 1 to File 500 AND File1 1 to File1 500)

Comment: I replaced `%newfile%` with `!newfile!` and got it to work for me.  I added the whole script I was using.

Comment: Have you check the Order, it works but not with the order the (File 10.pdf renamed to  002.pdf).

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood where the issue was.  The default sort order is not working for you.  That problem is addressed by michael_heath's answer.